# I can't think of a way to aviod dynamic variable in this case

Tags: python, python-3.x

*EDIT BELOW*

I read a lot of discussion about dynamic variable in python and a lot have shown that they are things that you generally shouldn't do. However I have a case that I really can't think of a way to avoid it (and hence why I am here)

I am currently reading in a text file that stores the information of different members of a store. Each members have their own information: like their phone number, email, points in their accounts, etc. I want to create a class and objects that stores this information. Don't worry this is just a part of an assignment and they are not real people. Here is the sample code:

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, name, phoneNumber, email, points):
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.email = email
        self.points = points
        self.totalPointsSpent = 0

    #There are methods below that will return some calculated results, like total points
    spent or their ranking. I will not show those here as they are irrelevant
```

And for each member in the file will be read in and create an object out of it. For example if there are 5 members in that file, five objects will be created, and I want to name them member1, member2, etc. However, this will be confusing when accessing it, as it will be hard to tell them apart, so I add them to a dictionary, with their memberID as the key:

```
dictonary[memberID] = member1
dictonary[memberID] = member2 #and so on
```

which would result in a dictionary that look like something like this:

```
dictionary = {'jk1234':member1,'gh5678':member2,...#etc}
```

This is the interesting thing about python is the fact that the dictionary value does not need to be a value, it can be an object. This is something new to me, coming from Java.

However, here is the first problem. I do not know how many member are there in a file, or I should say, the number of members in the file varies from file to file. If the number is 5, I need 5 variables; if there are 8, I need 8, and so on. I have thought of using a while loop, and the code will look something like this:

```
a = len(#the number of members in the file.)
i = 0
while i <= a:
    member + i = Member(#pass in the information)
```

but the '+' operator only works for strings when combining names, not for identifiers. And thus cannot work (I think).

Many solution I read has indicated that I should use a dictionary or a list in such case. However, since my variables are pointing towards a class object, I cannot think of a way to use list/dictionary as the implementation.

My current solution is to use a tuple to store the members information, and do the calculations elsewhere (i.e. I took out the class methods and defined them as functions) so that the dictionary looks like this:

```
dictionary = {'jk1234': (name, phoneNumber, email, points),'gh5678':(name, phoneNumber, email, points),...#etc}
```

However given the amount of information I need to pass in it is less than ideal. My current algorithm works, but I want to optimized it and make it more encapsulated.

If you made this far I appreciate it, and would like to know if there is a better algorithm for this problem. Please excuse me for my less than a year of Python experience.

EDIT: Okay I just discovered something really interesting that might seems basic to experienced Python programmers. That is you can pass the values inside the dictionary, instead of naming a variable exclusively. For my problem, that would be:

```
dictionary = {'jk1234': Member(name, phoneNumber, email, points),'gh5678':Member(name, phoneNumber, email, points),...#etc}
#and they are retrievable:
dictionary['jk1234'].get_score() #get_score is a getter function inside the class
```

And it would return the proper value. This seems to be a good solution. However, I would still love to hear other ways to think about this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track with your update.

It's not clear to me if your `MemberID` is a value for each member, but if it is, you can use it in a loop creating the objects

```py
d = {}

for member in members_file:
    d[MemberID] = Member(name, phoneNumber, email, points)
```

This, of course, assumes that `MemberID` is unique, otherwise you will overwrite existing entries.

You could also use a list instead

```py
l = []
for member in members_file:
    l.append(Member(name, phoneNumber, email, points))
```

Further, you could also do the above with list/dict comprehensions which are basically just condensed for-loops.

Dict-comprehension

```py
d = {MemberID: Member(name, phoneNumber, email, points) for member in members_file}
```

List-comprehension

```py
l = [Member(name, phoneNumber, email, points) for member in members_file]
```

Whether a list or a dictionary makes more sense, is up to your use-case.

Also note that the above assumes various things, e.g. on what form you get the data from the file, since you did not provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary with a for loop:

```
d = {}
for i in the_members_in_the_file:
    d[i] = Member(your, parameters, that\'s, inputted)
```

You will get your expected dictionary.